# Get duplicate Dart Project Issue

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I need to get copy or duplicate dart project from my friend, But when I get that and open existing folder and select that duplicate file. I am unable to run pub get, I got following error as

[image]

How can I copy a dart project from one system to another system, very strange problem. I run pub get more than 10 times.

Actually I delete all symlinks and again run pub get,pub upgrade the following error is occurs..[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have a permissions problem. There is nothing special about copying a Dart project. The `packages` directory and all `packages` symlinks in directories like `web`, `bin`, `test`, `example`, `tool`, should not be copied. If your copy includes these directories, just delete them and run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` again.

Comment: The error is still `'.\.packages' (OS Error: Access denied, errno = 5)`

Comment: thanks for your help. Yes I got it. I delete all files what you have mentioned and also delete '.packages' file(which is hidden in the root folder).